# query search laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel-5

I'm trying to have a user put any amount of numbers in a search bar and have those numbers match the to strings in my database that includes those numbers and pull the whole string.  I'm having a tough time getting it to work right now.  I'm trying to get it just work with 4 numbers and I figure that would be easier an feat, while also giving me a good concept of how to tackle the rest.  As of right now I'm not getting any errors, but it isn't displaying any information when I put in 4 numbers that i know should match an existing string.  The database I'm using is mysql.  This is what I have in my controller:

```
public function executeSearch()
{


    $search = Input::get('search');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['search'] = $search;
    $nsn_list_all = nsn::all();
    $query = \App\nsn::where('nsn_number', $search)->get();



    return View('Search_views.searchresults',compact('search', 'nsn_list_all', 'query'));
}
```

This is my view:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div class="main">
<br/>
    <h2>Search Results for {{$search}}:</h2>
   <br/>
    <table id="contact_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>National Stock Number</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                @foreach($query as $search_result)
                    @if($search_result->nsn_number == $search &&
                        $search_result->nsn_number[1] == $search[1] &&
                        $search_result->nsn_number[2] == $search[2] &&
                        $search_result->nsn_number[3] == $search[3])

                        <td>{{$search_result->nsn_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{$search_result->pn_name}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

On a side note without the `if` statement the the `foreach` statement works for finding the exact match though.

Comment: Why are you using `session_start` / `$_SESSION` instead of Laravel's built-in Session class?

Comment: already figured out how to do it,  and that was just more of exhausting all options and it doesn't actually effect my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  This will locate all the matching numbers in a string.

In the controller:

```
if ($search)
    {
        $nsn_query = DB::table('nsns')->where('nsn_number', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->get();
    }
```

The View:

```
 @foreach($nsn_query as $search_result)
       <td>{{$search_result->nsn_number}}</td>
       <td>{{$search_result->pn_name}}</td>
       <td></td>
 @endforeach
```

FYI Multiple results will run over and won't line break, about to work on that part, but I figured if anyone needed help figuring out the query part.